# Event listener for few elements at once

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to add listener for few elements at once?

What I'm doing currently is

```
$('#test1').on('click', function(event) {
    doSomething();
});
$('#test2').on('click', function(event) {
    doSomething();
});
$('#test3').on('click', function(event) {
    doSomething();
});
```

As you can see, all three IDs are triggering the same function.
How can I combine the code so I won't need to copy code for each listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#test1, #test2, #test3').on('click', function(event) {
   doSomething();
});
```

---

Or add a class to each one and use that:

```
$('.some-class').on('click', function(event) {
   doSomething();
});
```

---

Or for good measure, delegation (assuming they all start with the same thing):

```
$('body').on('click', '[id^=test]', function(event) {
   doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not ...

```
var all = [ "#test1", "#test2", "#test3" ];
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) { 
  $(all[i]).on('click', function (event) { 
    doSomething();
  });
}
```

Comment: @KevinB yep, that is what I was trying to write. I've been language hopping too much today and screwed up my syntax :(

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to probably select them all if they're a certain type in a container or add a class.

First example:

```
<div class="box">
  <a href="" id="test1">Test</a>
  <a href="" id="test1">Test</a>
  <a href="" id="test1">Test</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.box a').on('click', function(event) {
    doSomething();
});
```

Or adding a class:

```
<a href="" id="test1" class="button">Test</a>
<a href="" id="test1" class="button">Test</a>
<a href="" id="test1" class="button">Test</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(event) {
    doSomething();
});
```